# Trigger for creating new user

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have a table called **LOGIN_NAMES** which maintains a list of all login ids under the column **login_id**. I'm trying to write a trigger that creates a new user on inserting a value to **login_id** something like the below code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER login_id_create
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON  mySchema.LOGIN_NAMES
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  CREATE USER :NEW.login_id 
  IDENTIFIED BY password 
  DEFAULT TABLESPACE users
  QUOTA 10M ON users
  PASSWORD EXPIRE;

  GRANT CONNECT TO :NEW.login_id;
END
```

Isn't it possible to create users through triggers? If possible what would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a user is DDL.  DDL involves two implicit commits, one before the statement is run and once after the statement is run.  Triggers (unless declared to use autonomous transactions which would not be appropriate here) cannot commit or rollback a transaction.  So you can't issue DDL from a trigger.  You wouldn't want to if you could-- what if the transaction that inserted a row in `LOGIN_NAMES` was rolled back, for example, or what if Oracle had to execute the trigger multiple times for write consistency.

You could use the `dbms_job` package to submit a job that would run once the triggering transaction committed that would use dynamic SQL (`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` most likely) to create the user and run the `GRANT`.  I'm hard-pressed to imagine that you'd want that to happen on `UPDATE` rather than just on `INSERT` otherwise you'd be trying (and failing) to create a user every time someone updated some attribute in your table.  It would be a very unusual design to want to configure things this way-- if you want to maintain your own table to store information about users, that would normally mean that you want to create application users rather than Oracle users.  If you want to create Oracle users, it generally wouldn't make sense to create your own table to store that information, just take it from `dba_users`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I'm trying to develop a DBA tool to manage multiple DB servers. I've to manage information about users like email_id to notify about their quota (number of objects and schemas). So, I thought of maintaining user records separate. Could you please suggest a better way (or an alternative) to create a DB user by inserting a new record and dropping the user by deletion.

Comment: @Syam - I'd strongly prefer that the "DBA tool" that you develop directly issue the appropriate `CREATE USER` and `GRANT` statements after inserting whatever information you want in your custom table.  I don't see anything that is gained by having a trigger that submits a job that creates a user.